# Не вызывается AuthenticationSuccessHandler в Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Проблема следующая. Конфигурирую formLogin и хочу, чтобы в зависимости от роли пользователя, он редиректился после успешного логина на нужную страницу. Для этого сделал handler и добавил его в конфиг через .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler). Но метод хендлера onAuthenticationSuccess не вызывается, если указана своя страница для авторизации. Если в конфиге убрать строку .loginPage("/") - все работает, но используется стандартная страница авторизации Spring Security.
Что еще нужно сделать, чтобы использовать кастомную страницу авторизации и при этом использовать хендлер?

AuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> auths = authentication.getAuthorities();
        System.out.println("REDIRECT");
        boolean isAdmin = false;
        for (GrantedAuthority authority :auths) {
            if (authority.equals(Role.Roles.ADMIN.toString())) {
                isAdmin = true;
            }
        }
        if (isAdmin) {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(httpServletResponse.encodeURL("/admin"));
        } else {
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(httpServletResponse.encodeURL("/user"));
        }
    }
}
```

UserController:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    private final UserService userService;
    private final RoleService roleService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, RoleService roleService, PasswordEncoder passEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.roleService = roleService;
        this.passEncoder = passEncoder;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getIndex(@RequestParam(required = false) Boolean error, Model model) {
        if (error != null && error) {
            model.addAttribute("loginFailMessage", "Auth error!");
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("loginFailMessage", null);
        }
        return "login";
    }

...
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecutiryConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()

                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                .and()

                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .and()

                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(Role.Roles.ADMIN.toString())
                .and()

                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/") // <- Если закомментировать эту строку, handler работает
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureUrl("/?error=true")
                .permitAll()
                .and()

                .rememberMe()
                .authenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .alwaysRemember(true)
                .and()

                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>8.0.12</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
          <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <hibernate.version>5.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Там надо прилепить форму к конфигу

Comment: Какой uri указан для авторизации на странице?

Comment: @tequillaz на странице логина форму пробовал отправлять и на "/", и на "/login"

Comment: Добавьте форму в описание вопроса